# Problem subtracting matrices

Tags: matrix

I am trying to study eigenvalues and eigenvectors using Mathematica. I am trying to compute $A-\lambda I$, so I created a matrix A and a matrix with $\lambda$ in the diagonal:

```
A = {{1, 2, 1}, {6, -1, 0}, {-1, -2, -1}}

L = DiagonalMatrix[{\[Lambda], \[Lambda], \[Lambda]}] // MatrixForm
```

To compute the subtraction I evaluate `A - L // MatrixForm`, which yields the following output:

$\hskip2in$[image]

I was expecting, e.g., the first element to show as $1-\lambda$, ¿what is wrong? Any hints would be much appreciated!

Comment: `MatrixForm` is only for displaying purposes. Just don't use it.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher Just tried it but the problem persists, it only displays it differently.

Comment: Don't use `MatrixForm` _anywhere_. `A = {{1, 2, 1}, {6, -1, 0}, {-1, -2, -1}};
L = DiagonalMatrix[{\[Lambda], \[Lambda], \[Lambda]}];
A - L`

Comment: Just don't use `MatrixForm[]`. Remove all instances of it in your code. If it still does not work, please edit your question to show it, and we can release the hold.

Comment: @J.M.issomewhatokay. OK, that worked; thanks! What should I do with the question?